# consecutive prime power

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I'm interesting on consecutive prime power numbers. I see that there is the Mersenne primes and the Fermat Primes that give solutions and $(8,9)$. In Sloane collection it is referred on A006549 and it is written:

> David W. Wilson and Eric Rains found a simple proof that in this case of Catalan's conjecture either n or n+1 must be a power of 2 and the other number must be a prime, except for n=8.

But I can't find this proof on the web (and I don't find it myself...).

I tried the first case. I get a proof for $2^k+1=3^q$, but found it complicated. If someone has something simple?

Simple: I see that it's enough to consider the case $(2^k, q^n)$ because... ok it's clear

I see that it's enough to show that $2^k=-1$ mod $q$ or $q^2$ is impossible. But for exemple that give nothing for $2^k+1=5^q$ because $2$ is primite modulo $5$ and $25$ and so modulo all the $5^q$.

Comment: I don't believe there are any truly easy proofs for these. The prime pair (2,3) is sometimes given as a homework problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is indeed a relatively easy proof of the fact that if $n$ and $n+1$ are consecutive **prime powers**, then

1) Either $n$ or $n+1$ must be a power of 2.

2) Apart from $n=8$, the other number must be a prime.

**Note:** Here, the proof is relatively easy because we exploit the fact that the numbers are prime powers, and not just perfect powers. The proof of the full statement of Catalan's conjecture/Mihailescu's theorem is much harder.

---

**Proof:**

**1)** is trivial: One of $n, n+1$ must be even, hence must a power of $2$ since it is a prime power.

**2)** We have two cases ($n$ even or $n+1$ even)

**Case 1:** $n$ even. We have $n=2^a, n+1=p^b$, $p$ an odd prime, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus $2^a=p^b-1$.

If $b$ is even, then write $b=2c$.

$$2^a=p^b-1=(p^c-1)(p^c+1)$$

$p^c \pm 1$ are two powers of $2$ which differ by $2$, so must be $2$ and $4$. Thus $n=2^a=(2)(4)=8$. (the only exception where the other number is not prime)

If $b$ is odd, then

$$2^a=p^b-1=(p-1)(p^{b-1}+ \ldots +p+1)$$

$p^{b-1}+ \ldots +p+1 \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, so $p^{b-1}+ \ldots +p+1 \mid 2^a$ implies $p^{b-1}+ \ldots +p+1=1$. Thus $b=1$, so $n+1$ is a prime and we are done.

**Case 2:** $n$ odd. Then $n+1=2^a, n=p^b$, $p$ an odd prime, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus $2^a=p^b+1$.

If $b$ is even, then $p^b \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Thus $2^a=p^b+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$. Therefore $a=1$, so $n+1=2^a=2$, so $n=1$, a contradiction.

If $b$ is odd, then

$$2^a=p^b+1=(1+p)(p^{b-1}-p^{b-2}+ \ldots +p^2-p+1)$$

We have $(p^{b-1}-p^{b-2}+ \ldots +p^2-p+1) \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, and $(p^{b-1}-p^{b-2}+ \ldots +p^2-p+1)$ is a power of $2$, so $(p^{b-1}-p^{b-2}+ \ldots +p^2-p+1)=1$. Thus $b=1$, so $n$ is a prime and we are done.

Comment: Thanks. If no mistakes I found an other proof of that. It seems curious that one waits so long time (Wilson and Rains) to establish this fact that seems not so difficult. Maybe Sloane site made a mistake?