# Do there exist arbitrary large $n,n+1$ so that they are both prime powers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Hello I am rather new to number theory and only know some very basics. This question has been bugging me for some time.

Is there an upper bound to $\{n,n+1\}$ for which
$$\begin{array}{rr}n=&{p_1}^{k_1}\\n+1=&{p_2}^{k_2}\end{array}$$
Where $p_1,p_2$ prime. Preferrably with $k_1>k_0$ and $k_2>k_0$ for some smallest exponent $k_0$.

Comment: If there is, either $p_1$ or $p_2$ is equals 2

Comment: One of them must be of the form $2^n $

Comment: This question was asked and answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735653/

Comment: Not only does one prime have to be $2$, the other prime power should actually be a prime, with the exception of the pair $(8,9) $.

Comment: @Shagnik Hence this question is open because it's equivalent to the infinitude of the union of Fermat and Mersenne primes.

Comment: @ErickWong Haha true, perhaps "answered" was a bit strong. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an upper bound:
$$8=2^3$$
$$8+1=3^2$$
You are asking whether there are infinitely many consecutive prime powers, and the answer is no. In fact, the solution above is the only non-trivial case of consecutive powers *in general*, and this is the statement of Mihailescu's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The  only consecutive perfect powers are $8$ and $9$. This was formerly known as Catalan's conjecture, and is now a theorem proved in 2002.

Comment: Wow, as late as 2002, fascinating.

Comment: What was proven by in 2002 wasn't that after removing the prime requirement, which supposedly is a much harder problem than if one can assume they are primes?