# Can there be three consecutive numbers of the form p^a, q^b , r^c where p, q and r are prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can there be three consecutive positive integers  of the form p^a, q^b , r^c  where p, q and r are prime numbers? other than  (2,3,4),    (3,4,5), (7,8,9). In fact 2, 3, 4, 5 gives 4 consecutive integers in which each number is either a prime or a pirme power.
example 8, 9 and 10 --> 2^3, 3^2, 2X5 the third number is not  a prime power. similarly 25, 26, 27 --> 5^2, 2X13, 3^3 the middle one is not a prime power.
The numbers can only be of the form 2n-1, 2n, 2n+1 ,  where n=  2^m  , 2n+1 = 3^k ,    2n-1 is a prime >5 or prime power.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735653/consecutive-prime-power)

Comment: The (proven) Catalan conjecture rules out many possibilities.

Comment: I believe that the question Lulu linked to can be used to deduce that it is impossible other than in the cases you enumerated.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Steven Stadnicki the three integers must contain one divisible by $3$ and at least one divisible by $2$. Therefore two consecutive numbers have the form $2^m$ and $3^n$.

Note that, $3^{2k+1}\equiv 3$ (mod $8$) and $3^{2k}\equiv 1$ (mod $8$).

If $2^m=3^{2k}\pm1$ or $2^m=3^{2k+1}+1$ then $2^m$ is $2$ or $4$ modulo $8$ and is therefore $2$ or $4$.

If $2^m=3^{2k}-1=(3^k-1)(3^k+1)$ then $3^k+1$ is $2$ or $4$ modulo $8$. Therefore  $2^m=8$.

The solutions for the two consecutive integers are $(2,3), (3,4), (8,9)$.

The solutions for the three prime powers are $(2,3,4), (3,4,5), (7,8,9)$.

Answer (score 0):

The only consecutive primes are $\space 2\space$ and
$\space 3\space$ and you have already eliminated combinations among $\space 2,3,4,5.\quad$  One alternative is to find some power of $\space 2\space $ that is between twin primes greater than $\space 5.\space$ This would be a twin prime where the lower number is a
[Mersenne_prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)
$\space (M_n).\quad$ A problem with this is that it appears that
$\space 3\mid(M_n+2),\space n>1.\quad$ I don't believe the triple you seek exists.

Comment: It's pretty quick to show that $3|(M_n+2)$, and this gives a further constraint that points towards impossibility: one of the three numbers $M_n=2^n-1$, $2^n$, $2^n+1$ must be divisible by three. (As indeed, one of any three consecutive numbers does). This means that any trio such as OP desires has to have a power of two _and_ a power of three in it.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Very good logic, and obvious once seen. I don’t know why I didn’t see that before.